# HTTP GET for ASMX Services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, http-get

I'm trying to enable a webservice to accept HTTPGet. I've done this in the past, but I have a feeling BlogEngine.NET may be interfering somehow. I've added these sections to web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

And my method has this signature:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]
public void GetCurrent(string setupType)
```

Yet when I call the service, I just get the the WSDL description page. I'm trying to binary write a file to track numbers of downloads, so I have a rewrite rule to redirect what looks like a .zip file to my download service. The rewriting works fine as I see the WSDL file, but the method isn't invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same result using a generic handler (ashx). I believe BlogEngine.NET interferes with the way services are mapped somehow.